# Issue in kaminari ajax pagination

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

Am using kaminari ajax pagination in my project. It is working fine, But contents are displaying number of pages times in the page. For example if number of items per pages is 7, then it is displaying 7 times the same content. What am doing is

In product_details controller

```
  def index
    @products=ProductDetail.where("department_id = ? and category_id = ?",1, 1).page(params[:page]).per(15)
  end
```

In product_details/index.html.erb

```
<div id="product_details">
    <%= render @products %>
</div>
<div id="paginator">
    <%= paginate @products, :remote=>true %>
</div>
```

In product_details/index.js.erb

```
$('#product_details').html('<%= escape_javascript render (@products) %>');
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@products, :remote=>true).to_s)%>');
```

In product_details/_product_detail.html.erb

```
<div id="product_list">             
    <% @products.each do | product | %> 
        <div class="product_container">     
            <div class="product_box" >
                <div id="future_image_container">
                    <div class="image_block" >
                        <%= image_tag(product.image_path, :alt => "product image", :height=>"215px") %>
                    </div>
                    <span id="future_price" style="text-decoration: line-through; color: #9e9c9c;">
                        <span style="color: black;">
                            <%=  "$#{product.price}" %>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <div id="circle">
                        <p>
                            <% if(product.discount > 0) %>
                                <% new_price=((2.0*((product.price*product.discount)/100)).round)/2.0 %>
                            <% else %>
                                <% new_price=product.price %>
                            <% end %>
                            <%= "$#{new_price}"%>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="future_product_name">
                    <%= product.name %>
                </p>
                <% @brands=Brand.where("id=?",product.brand_id)
                    @brands.each do |brand|
                        @brandname=brand.name
                    end
                %>
                <p class="future_product_name">
                    <%= "Brand : #{@brandname}" %>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that when i use <%= render @products %> how many items i have taken per page that number of times it repeates. Therefore I solved this by the following code:

In product_details controller

```
  def index
    @products=ProductDetail.where("department_id = ? and category_id = ?",1, 1).page(params[:page]).per(15)
  end
```

In product_details/home.html.erb

```
<div id="product_details">
    <%= render 'index' %>
</div>
```

In product_details/index.js.erb

```
$('#product_details').html('<%= escape_javascript render ('index') %>');
```

In product_details/_index.html.erb

```
<div id="product_list">
    <%= paginate @products, :remote=>true %>                
    <% @products.each do | product | %> 
        <div class="product_container">     
            <div class="product_box" >
                <div id="future_image_container">
                    <div class="image_block" >
                        <%= image_tag(product.image_path, :alt => "product image", :height=>"215px") %>
                    </div>
                    <span id="future_price" style="text-decoration: line-through; color: #9e9c9c;">
                        <span style="color: black;">
                            <%=  "$#{product.price}" %>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <div id="circle">
                        <p>
                            <% if(product.discount > 0) %>
                                <% new_price=((2.0*((product.price*product.discount)/100)).round)/2.0 %>
                            <% else %>
                                <% new_price=product.price %>
                            <% end %>
                            <%= "$#{new_price}"%>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="future_product_name">
                    <%= product.name %>
                </p>
                <% @brands=Brand.where("id=?",product.brand_id)
                    @brands.each do |brand|
                        @brandname=brand.name
                    end
                %>
                <p class="future_product_name">
                    <%= "Brand : #{@brandname}" %>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Now no product repeates and ajax pagination is also working fine